# iOS - Getting current AVPlayer(Item) state

Tags: ios, streaming, ios9, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm looking for a definitive answer how to get current `AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem` state on iOS 9 onwards. To put things simple, let them be Google's ExoPlayer style states:

- **idle** (no media or error)
- **buffering** (video is not actually playing/advancing and waiting for
  more data)
- **playing** (video is actually playing/advancing)
- **completed** (video finished playing to the end)

Note, that at this point I'm not looking for a way to track state changes (via notifications, KVO-observing or other means), just a state at current point of time. Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    PlayerStateIdle,
    PlayerStateBuffering,
    PlayerStatePlaying,
    PlayerStateCompleted
} PlayerState;

+ (PlayerState)resolvePlayerState:(AVPlayer*)player {
    // Magic code here
}
```

Walls, I've been banging my head against so far:

- `timeControlStatus` available from iOS 10 onwards
- `playbackBufferEmpty` is always true
- `playbackBufferFull` is always false
- `loadedTimeRanges` may look promising at first glance, but there's neither an indication of how much time must be pre-buffered for playback nor guarantee that `currentTime` being on the edge of loaded time range is a stall

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation

> You can use Key-value observing to observe these state changes as they
>   occur. One of the most important player item properties to observe is
>   its status. The status indicates if the item is ready for playback and
>   generally available for use.

To setup observing:

```
func prepareToPlay() {
    let url = <#Asset URL#>
    // Create asset to be played
    asset = AVAsset(url: url)

    let assetKeys = [
        "playable",
        "hasProtectedContent"
    ]
    // Create a new AVPlayerItem with the asset and an
    // array of asset keys to be automatically loaded
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset,
                              automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: assetKeys)

    // Register as an observer of the player item's status property
    playerItem.addObserver(self,
                           forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status),
                           options: [.old, .new],
                           context: &playerItemContext)

    // Associate the player item with the player
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
}
```

To handle:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                           of object: Any?,
                           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                           context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    // Only handle observations for the playerItemContext
    guard context == &playerItemContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                           of: object,
                           change: change,
                           context: context)
        return
    }

    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status) {
        let status: AVPlayerItemStatus

        // Get the status change from the change dictionary
        if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
            status = AVPlayerItemStatus(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
        } else {
            status = .unknown
        }

        // Switch over the status
        switch status {
        case .readyToPlay:
        // Player item is ready to play.
        case .failed:
        // Player item failed. See error.
        case .unknown:
            // Player item is not yet ready.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is.

You can just access player.status or player.timeControlStatus and return a result that matches your ENUM

Is that what you mean?

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question, I was looking for iOS 9+ soluton and 'timeControlStatus' property is available from iOS 10. Anyway, other parts of AVPlayer (e.g. prerolls) are majorily broken, so I've ended up with writing my own wrapper over AVPlayer instance, which does it's own state tracking based on 'loadedTimeRanges' values.